# Android, repeat an action over a specified time period

Tags: android, repeat, audio

I have the following "if condition" from accelerometer values and when the device is flat a beep sound is being played continuously. I can not figure out how can I make this sound to be **repeated** over a specified time period (example: 5 seconds). I tried many ways and all the time the sound is still being played all the time or does not follow the if condition. If someone could help me..Thank you in advance..

```
if (x > -0.1 && x < 0.1 && y > -0.1 && y < 0.1) {
  try {
    AssetFileDescriptor afd = getAssets().openFd("beep.wav");
    mMediaplayer = new MediaPlayer();
    mMediaplayer.setDataSource(afd.getFileDescriptor(), afd.getStartOffset(), afd.getLength());
    afd.close();
    mMediaplayer.prepare();
    mMediaplayer.start();
    mMediaplayer.setOnCompletionListener(new OnCompletionListener() {
      public void onCompletion(MediaPlayer mp) {
        //mp.setLooping(false);
        mp.stop();
        mp.release();
      }
    });
  } catch (Exception e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Why dont you play the Media Player in a new Async Task in the background? Create your own async task implementation and then just pass a time value in its constructor and then start the mediaplayer there and keep checking in it to see if the elapsed time duration is equal to the value passed to it. I think this might help -->

http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/AsyncTask.html

Answer (score 0):

You can use a repeating alarm.

```
int secondsInterval = 5; // 5 seconds for example
long interval = secondsInterval * 1000;
long firstTime = Calendar.getInstance().getTimeInMillis();

Intent i = new Intent(ctx, AlarmHandler.class);
PendingIntent mAlarmSender = PendingIntent.getService(ctx, 0, i, PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT);

AlarmManager am = (AlarmManager) ctx.getSystemService(ALARM_SERVICE);
am.setRepeating(AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP, firstTime, interval, mAlarmSender);
```

Then you should include your code inside a method like this in the Intent handler class (AlarmHandler.class in the above code):

```
@Override
protected void onHandleIntent(Intent arg0) {
    // your code here
}
```